# Crop a UIImage using a UIView frame

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I have the following function to crop a portion of a UIImage and return the cropped UIImage. I pass in the frame of a UIView which is serving as kind of a moveable box for the user to crop the image with. The UIView sits ontop of the UIImage and when the user presses confirm, I attempt to crop the portion of the UIImage underneath the UIView.

```
private func cropImage(image: UIImage, cropRect: CGRect) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(cropRect.size, false, 0)
    image.draw(at:CGPoint(x: -cropRect.origin.x, y: -cropRect.origin.y))

    let croppedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return croppedImage!;
}

@IBAction func confirmTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let croppedImage = cropImage(image: backgroundImage!, cropRect: mediaView.frame)
}
```

I am getting the original UIImage using a camera framework, and it's worth noting my phone is in portrait mode when taking the picture:

```
let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(sampleBuffer!)
let dataProvider = CGDataProvider(data: imageData as CFData)
let cgImageRef = CGImage(jpegDataProviderSource: dataProvider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true, intent: CGColorRenderingIntent.defaultIntent)

let image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImageRef!, scale: 1.0, orientation: self.getImageOrientation(forCamera: self.currentCamera))
```

**The problem** I'm having is that the result cropped UIImage is blown up/zoomed in and not representing the actual area underneath/within the frame of the UIView.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the screen scale as a parameter?

```
let image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImageRef!, scale: UIScreen.main.scale, orientation: self.getImageOrientation(forCamera: self.currentCamera))
```

Add the scale to the UIGraphicsBeginImageContext as well:

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(cropRect.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen.scale)
```

Comment: Still no luck with this

Comment: it is because you are passing the frame and not the pixel size. When you crop an image you need to the pixel height and width